# python script to monitor execution of a function on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that communicates to a device over serial interface. There is a function `my_fn()` to be exectuted which sends some commands to the serial interface and waits for `recieved_fn()` to be triggered by device. If `recieved_fn()` is not triggered within 5 sec then execute `my_fn()` again.
How should I monitor if `recieved_fn()` is executed or not within a time period of 5 seconds.
I am running python 2.7 on windows 10.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is hard to provide a generic correct answer without seeing your code and what you are using. What exactly in your code is calling `received_fn`?

Are you using some sort of event loop that allows event registering? If yes, then you should also use that event loop's timing methods to timeout the triggering.

A more generic approach would be to use a global variable or attribute to do the monitoring.

If you're using threads then maybe an event object is what you want, as they allow waiting with a timeout: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects